# How to make LightGBM to suppress output?

Tags: python, boosting, lightgbm

I have tried for a while to figure out how to "shut up" LightGBM. Especially, I would like to suppress the output of LightGBM during training (i.e. feedback on the boosting steps).

My model:

```
params = {
            'objective': 'regression',
            'learning_rate' :0.9,
            'max_depth' : 1,
            'metric': 'mean_squared_error',
            'seed': 7,
            'boosting_type' : 'gbdt'
        }

gbm = lgb.train(params,
                lgb_train,
                num_boost_round=100000,
                valid_sets=lgb_eval,
                early_stopping_rounds=100)
```

I tried to add `verbose=0` as suggested in the docs, but this does not work.
https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/docs/Parameters.rst

Does anyone know how to suppress LightGBM output during training?

Comment: Perhaps it's `verbose_eval` you're looking for? https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python-API.html

Comment: Yep, got rid of most feedback! Thanks! Any idea how I can also suppress warnings, because I still receive a lot of warnings as feedback.

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: It is „No further splits with positive gain“, likely caused by min_data_in_leaf. However, I would like to keep the configuration. My current application is a parameter search.

Comment: This is the latest I update on the issue that I can see: https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1157#issuecomment-417373690

Comment: Thanks! I‘ll check it soon. If you feel like, post your combined answers/suggestions in as answer, so others can follow it and I can vote it up. Cheers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Peter has suggested, setting `verbose_eval = -1` suppresses most of `LightGBM` output (link: [here](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python-API.html)).

However, `LightGBM` may still return other warnings - e.g. `No further splits with positive gain`. This can be suppressed as follows (source: [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1157#issuecomment-417373690) ):

```
lgb_train = lgb.Dataset(X_train, y_train, params={'verbose': -1}, free_raw_data=False)
lgb_eval = lgb.Dataset(X_test, y_test, params={'verbose': -1},free_raw_data=False)
gbm = lgb.train({'verbose': -1}, lgb_train, valid_sets=lgb_eval, verbose_eval=False)
```

Answer (score 8):

Solution for sklearn API (checked on v3.3.0):

```
import lightgbm as lgb


param = {'objective': 'binary', "is_unbalance": 'true',
         'metric': 'average_precision'}
model_skl = lgb.sklearn.LGBMClassifier(**param)

# early stopping and verbosity
# it should be 0 or False, not -1/-100/etc
callbacks = [lgb.early_stopping(10, verbose=0), lgb.log_evaluation(period=0)]

# train
model_skl.fit(x_train, y_train,
              eval_set=[(x_train, y_train), (x_val, y_val)],
              eval_names=['train', 'valid'],
              eval_metric='average_precision',
              callbacks=callbacks)
```

Comment: Confirmed. `log_evaluation(0)` is the important piece for turning off the booster updates.

Answer (score 6):

To suppress (most) output from LightGBM, the following parameter can be set.

**Suppress warnings:** `'verbose': -1` must be specified in `params={}`.

**Suppress output of training iterations:** `verbose_eval=False` must be specified in the `train{}` parameter.

Minimal example:

```
params = {
            'objective': 'regression',
            'learning_rate' : 0.9, 
            'max_depth' : 1, 
            'metric': 'mean_squared_error',
            'seed': 7,
            'verbose': -1,
            'boosting_type' : 'gbdt'
        }

gbm = lgb.train(params,
                lgb_train,
                num_boost_round=100000,
                valid_sets=lgb_eval,
                verbose_eval=False,
                early_stopping_rounds=100)
```

Answer (score 4):

Follow these points.

1. Use `verbose= False` in `fit` method.
2. Use `verbose= -100` when  you call the classifier.
3. Keep `silent = True` (default).

Answer (score 1):

I read all the answers and issues, and tried all these approaches and yet LGBM still outputs some info (which drives me crazy). If you want to completely suppress any output during the training try this out:

```
with open(os.devnull, "w") as f, contextlib.redirect_stdout(f):
    gbm = lgb.cv(param, lgb_dataset)
```

Comment: This was the only way it worked right now. Thanks.